# How to get authorization code from Pinterest

Tags: oauth, pinterest

I am trying to get authorization code from Pinterest.

I went through [the official docs](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/) and they stated to make a request this parameters as :

```
https://api.pinterest.com/oauth/?
    response_type=code&
    redirect_uri=https://mywebsite.com/connect/pinterest/&
    client_id=12345&
    scope=read_public,write_public&
    state=768uyFys
```

where I changed

- redirect_uri=http://localhost&
- client_id=to_MyClient_Id&

remaining parameters unchanged and I hit the request on postman.

And the response I am getting is :

```
{
  "status": "failure",
  "message": "Invalid parameters.",
  "code": 1,
  "data": "Missing required field 'scope'"
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
 https://api.pinterest.com/oauth/?
 state=1234567890&scope=read_public&client_id={your app 
 id}&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com&response_type=code
```

Try this parameter order(state as first,scope,...etc)!! very weird, really!! just cut out the scope and paste it in the end and you'll response saying another field missing and do again and again the same parameter order change until you get the website HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using V5 of the Pinterest API?
If yes, your scopes are incorrect. read_public > pins:read

Check the scopes here
https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/getting-started/scopes/

When you have an app you want to use the app flow with an access token, but don't want to created the whole flow yourself, just for the access token, you can use this tool online
https://frederik.today/codehelper/tools/oauth-access-token-pinterest